# Notice warnings dealing with PHP

Tags: php

I am making a quiz on a webpage for my media class, however, I am running into trouble. When i submit my quiz, I am receiving notices that say:

> Notice: Undefined variable: all_my_variables in /var/www/html/horvati2-results.php on line 65
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: current_timestamp in /var/www/html/horvati2-results.php on line 69
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: SERVER in /var/www/html/horvati2-results.php on line 70

This portion of my PHP looks like this:

```
    $csv_filehandle = fopen("/var/www/html/data/quiz.csv",'a');
    fputcsv($csv_filehandle,array($summer,$spring,$fall,$winter));
    fclose ($csv_filehandle);
    
    $visit_id = uniqid('',TRUE);
    
    $json_filehandle = fopen("/var/www/html/data/$visit_id.json",'w');
    fwrite($json_filehandle,json_encode($all_my_variables));
    fclose($json_filehandle);

    $all_my_variables = array(
        'timestamp' => $current_timestamp,
        'user_ip' => $SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'summer' => $summer,
        'spring' => $spring,
        'fall' => $fall,
        'winter' => $winter,
    );
    
    
    $current_hour = date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
    $current_timestamp = date(DATE_RFC822);
```

I would greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: Look at your code again, you're doing it all backwards! First you try to use those variables, then you define what they are?!

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to programming! Thank you for the responses that helped a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

`$current_timestamp` doesn't exist; don't try to use it.

`$SERVER` is a typo; it's supposed to be `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Thank you! What variable should I use to include a timestamp then? I have been trying to look it up but I'm still unsure.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is from this line:

```
fwrite($json_filehandle,json_encode($all_my_variables));
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

at the point this code executes, all_my_variables hasn't been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable: `$all_my_variables` before you have declared it (2 lines later).

Try putting that above the line:

```
$json_filehandle = fopen("/var/www/html/data/$visit_id.json",'w');
```